# How to create a multiple uploader in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to create a multiple uploader in wordpress but the media files upload at the time of submit form so basically required mutliple file uploader in jquery with progress bar and the files will upload into wordpress media when form submit.

Thanks

Comment: May be you should ask at wordpress.stackexchange.com instead. Without some code that is used now and without showing some attempts of your own, this sounds as both off-topic and too broad.

Comment: [this](https://lv.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/screenshots/) seems like what you are looking for. Are you sure you want to create a new?